# Image not showing using Python and Flask on Google Colab

Tags: python, image, flask, google-colaboratory

I want to show an image using Python and Flask on Google Colab, however, the resulting webpage doesn't show the image. Please find below my code. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Regards,
Ben

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

from flask_ngrok import run_with_ngrok
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/flasktest/templates', static_folder='/content/drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks/flasktest/static')
run_with_ngrok(app)

@app.route('/')
def main():
    return '<html><body><img src="cross.png"></body></html>'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `url_for`

```
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return '<html><body><img src="{{url_for('static',filename = './cross.png')}}"></body></html>'
```

`'static'` there refers to your `static_folder` path.